# 再帰について、この解釈は正しいでしょうか

Tags: javascript

Recursionについて学習中なのですが、わからない箇所があるので質問します。

**学習内容ページ:**
[Basic JavaScript: Replace Loops using Recursion - freeCodeCamp.org](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/replace-loops-using-recursion)

前提として、

> ```
>   function multiply(arr, n) {
>     var product = 1;
>     for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
>         product *= arr[i];
>     }
>     return product;
>   }
> ```
>
> しかし、 **`multiply(arr, n) == multiply(arr, n - 1) * arr[n - 1]`** なので、下記のように書き換えられる。
>
> ```
>   function multiply(arr, n) {
>     if (n <= 0) {
>       return 1;
>     } else {
>       return multiply(arr, n - 1) * arr[n - 1];
>     }
>   }
> ```

つまり、仮に

```
  function multiply(arr, n) {                               
    if (n <= 0) {                               
      return 1;                             
    } else {                                
      return multiply(arr, n - 1) * arr[n - 1];                             
    }                               
  }                             
arr=[2,3,4,5,6,7];
multiply(arr, 5);
```

だとして、**n=5,4,3,2,1(arrの内容で言うと 6,5,4,3,2)を順番に処理し、
elseのreturn値が`multiply(arr, n - 1) * arr[n - 1];    //6*5*4*3*2 = 720`　となったところでn=0に達し、最後は、returnされた1が代入されるので、`結果 720*1 ＝ 720`　となるということでしょうか。

解釈は、これで正しいのでしょうか。

どなたか、お答えいただければ幸いです。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: javascriptを、デバッグでステップ実行する方法を学ぶのがプログラムの動きを確認するのに役に立ちます。ブラウザの、F12キーを使う方法と、Visual studio code などの開発者ツールを使う方法かあります。調べたら役立つと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

・追加の質問について
元の質問を消してしまうと、回答と意味が繋がらなくなるため推奨されません。
なるべく追記する形にしたほうが良いです。

実行の流れとしては再起呼び出しのため、先にmultiplyの関数が展開され、
multiply(arr,0)->1がreturnされたあと順次さかのぼって計算されていきます。
イメージとしては下記のようになります。

```
multiply(arr,5)
->multiply(arr,4)*6
  ->(multiply(arr,3)*5)*6
    ->((multiply(arr,2)*4)*5)*6
      ->(((multiply(arr,1)*3)*4)*5)*6      
        ->((((multiply(arr,0)*2)*3)*4)*5)*6
        ->((((1*2)*3)*4)*5)*6
      ->(((2*3)*4)*5)*6
    ->((6*4)*5)*6
  ->(24*5)*6
->120*6
=720
```

Answer (score 0):

multiplyで行っている処理は、配列 arr の先頭から n 個の要素の積を返す関数です。
つまり、返り値はarr[0]～arr[n-1]までの積となります。

```
if arr = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
multiply(arr, 5); equals 2*3*4*5*6  //arr[4]=6
```

になります。
上段multiply内のfor内でも i<n となっているのでarr[n-1]の要素までしかアクセスしていません。

Comment: 新たに不明点が出てきてしまったため質問内容を修正しました。ご回答いただいた箇所について、理解できました。ありがとうございます。^^